# How to set env variable in Heroku with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

How to set env variable Heroku with Node.js? I opened Heroku account but unable to find out the possible solution to set my env variables up.

Comment: Did you read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars? The language you're using is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your deployed app settings. Then, in "config vars" section click on "Reveal Config Vars" button and you can enter env variables there, which will be also available in your application

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Seems like the OP is really confusing, maybe a link to the Help center of heroku will help This maybe even a link to a video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g81LARb914Y

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to set it up. You can either use the Heroku CLI to update the same. In your command line, after installing the Heroku cli,

Run
`heroku config:set ENV_VARIABLE=VALUE`

Also If you want to update the env variables on Heroku Dashboard,
Go to your app settings.
There is a button called "Reveal Config Vars", You can add and update the same there without any cli usage.

All of these details are available [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)